# Is it possible for a Chrome Extension to get a user's full browsing history?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a yes / no answer here.

I've gathered that it's possible to get the pages linked to by 'back' and 'forward' buttons but I'm looking for a list of *all* the entries. I won't know the domains ahead of time, so if I needed to use a search parameter it would need to be a wildcard.

I was hoping there'd be some HTML5 permission similar to geolocation or microphone / webcam recording, but I'm seeing Chrome Extensions as the promising approach to get these enhanced permissions. Not to bash other browsers, it's just what I personally use.

Comment: I don't believe it can access the history, but one with sufficient permissions could log all pages viewed from the point of its installation onwards.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

Comment: @DanielHerr I stand corrected!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is using the history api: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history

```
chrome.history.search({text: '', maxResults: 10}, function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(page) {
        console.log(page.url);
    });
});
```

from: [How to get browsing history using history API in Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894627/how-to-get-browsing-history-using-history-api-in-chrome-extension)

Comment: This gets just 10 items, not the full history that the question is asking for.

Comment: @jdunning you could easily change that to something that won't hinder the results, like Infinity (or, even better, remove that object property altogether).