# Is it possible to color unvisited links that have the same hostname as visited links?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, hyperlink, hostname

I'm trying to make links leading to a website appear visited if I've ever visited it, regardless of what part I visited. For example, if I visit "example.com/abc" any links to that exact URL will appear visited and their style will change accordingly, but I'd like for links to "example.com" and "example.com/xyz" to appear visited as well because I visited "example.com/abc". I know the CSS to change visited link colors would be `a:visited {color: red}`, but as I am very much a Javascript novice, I can't figure out how to get from there to then changing link colors for any visited hostname.

If it's important, I'm using a browser extension to run the Javascript and CSS, and it's just for fun while I'm trying to learn the languages. Thank you very much!

Comment: I do not think that is possible via CSS. You can however get all links on the page and then strip all but the host from them, pass them e.g. to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894627/how-to-get-browsing-history-using-history-api-in-chrome-extension to find possible matches and then react accordingly.

Comment: Which browser does the extension run in?

Comment: @yunzen Chrome.

Comment: I don't think browsers will let you sense what has been visited (in the past). You may need some way of storing the information yourself.