# How do I extract my comprehensive browser history from local browser profile files programatically?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, browser-history

I setup an isolated Chrome browser profile by using a command line switch in a Windows shortcut:

```
%CHROME_EXE% --user-data-dir=g:\profiles\chrome\<user_dir>\
```

If this directory is empty, when I launch Chrome with this shortcut, all profile files will be created.

My browser history is in there somewhere.

---

I know where my profile directory is and I can list/see all files.

I want to write a program (Java, Python or Rust), to extract my browser history data.

I want to extract the URL and date of last visit.

How would this be possible?  Is there an example project with example code that would do this?

Is there any information that can be obtained about the profile files as to which file to look at (if it's a database file or a plain text file), and how to extract data?

---

I have looked at other similar Stackoverflow posts, and none fully answers this question (that is recent and pertains to the latest browser release).

Thank You,

Comment: Hi ! Are you trying to hack these encrypted files ? An easier approach could be to use [the existing api](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/history/) in an extension :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "hack".  I want to extract my browser history that is located in files on my local machine.

Comment: These files are (fortunately) encrypted, for security reasons, and so not directly readable. But a browser extension can read the history, that's why I've provided you a link to the relevant api :)

Comment: An interesting post about how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24894627/4698373)

Comment: I will give this a try.  This is really scary if every site I visit can read and collect my web history.

Comment: In fact not exactly : the extension has to declare this in its manifest file, and then, **if the user accepts it**, it gets access to the history. But it doesn't mean that every site can also view your history ! Only the extension can do it, and it's up to the developer to process the collected data with discernment ;)

Comment: Hey ! Did you match your goal ? Technically speaking, I didn't answer to your question, but I hope my advice has been relevant ^^